# Redirect one file in Amazon S3 to external domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Let's say I have an object at `http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/folder1/folder2/pdf/something.pdf`

There are NO other files in the bucket as this was setup for a legacy link that is being used in an old marketing campaign.

I want that link to redirect to `https://example.com`  (the screenshot has a different domain but SO won't let me post it here).

Tried to setup static hosting with variations of this but can't seem to get this to work.    Is there a way to do a redirect for this one file?

In the interim I had to add a blank pdf that just has a link for the user to click which isn't ideal.

[image]

Comment: If you setup s3 website, it should work but the url will be different. Example, you should be able to redirect `http://www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/folder1/folder2/pdf/something.pdf`. I guess this is NOT what you want, is it? Do you need the original URL to be `http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/folder1/folder2/pdf/something.pdf`?

Comment: That is correct.  This is an old marketing campaign (10+ years maybe) pointing to that link but the original file was removed, we just want to redirect it to the website if possible instead of showing an empty pdf with the link in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [guide](https://salferrarello.com/s3-url-redirect/) will work for you.

Basically it replaces the obsolete file with an HTML file, while retaining the old name `something.pdf`. The HTML contains meta header `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.example.com/target/">` that should force an instant redirect to the desired location. Make sure to edit the file metadata ContentType to `text/html` so that the browser is able to read it.

I tried this myself as well, it works!

Answer (score 1):

The other option seems to be "Redirect requests for an object". Instructions are in the official documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html

Comment: I was unable to get it to redirect, hence the post.